# Unable to extract value based on keys from a .CLJ file

Tags: json, function, api, dictionary, clojure

I have gotten JSON info from an open API using

`(def station-info (clj-http.client/get statinfo {:as :json}))`

I have spit that information into a .clj file defined as si. It's content look like this:

```
{:stations [{:station_id "1755", :name "Aker Brygge", :address "Aker Brygge",
             :lat 59.91118372188379, :lon 10.730034556850455, :capacity 33}
            {:station_id "1101", :name "Stortingstunellen", :address "Rådhusgata 34",
             :lat 59.91065301806209, :lon 10.737365277561025, :capacity 24}]}
```

When I call the function (map :station_id (:stations si)) it returns an empty list "()".

But if I define a function with the same info in the REPL and then use the same function, it works!

Very strange.

---

**EDIT**: Fixed it by turning the string from the file into a data structure:

```
(def si-data-structure (edn/read-string (slurp si)))
```

Comment: `si` vs `station-info` maybe?

Comment: Instead of editing your question to answer itself, please add an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is right, so your data must be wrong. In particular, you will surely find that `(:stations si)` is also empty. Look at the `si` variable and see if it really contains what you expect: is it a map? Is `:stations` one of its keys?

Comment: The si variable contains a map with one key :stations which has a vector of maps as its value.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it by turning the string from the file into a data structure:

```
(def si-data-structure (edn/read-string (slurp si)))
```